# Maven build in Eclipse Luna IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7, eclipse-luna

I want to develop a simple test program as maven project in eclipse IDE.
What are the prerequisite and procedure to run this program.

Comment: This question is too broad, have a look around for tutorials/etc and please do come back with some specific questions if you run into problems or want to understand something in greater depth.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/maven/) for all prerequisite and step by step approach